# Tensorflow, what is saved with tf.train.Saver?

Tags: tensorflow

I am wondering what exactly is saved when I use a tf.train.Saver() to save my model after every training epoch.  The file seems kind of large compared to what I am used to with Keras models.  Right now my RNN takes up 900 MB at each save.  Is there any way to tell the saver to only save the trainable parameters?  I would also like a way to save only part of the model.  I know I can just get the variables I define and save them using the numpy format but when I use the RNN classes I don't directly have access to their weights and I looked through the code and there is nothing like get_weights that I can see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can provide a list of variables to save in the `Saver` constructor, ie `saver=tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.trainable_variables())`

Comment: This is incomplete as some variables are not trainable but are still saved by the Saver.

Comment: Hi, I wonder to know, if the network contains BN layers, what should I do? Because the mean and variance are variables, but they are not trainable. If I only save tf.tf.trainable_variables(), when I restore the model, tensorflow can't find the BN mean parameters......

Answer (score 4):

It will save all `variables._all_saveable_objects()` by default, if `Saver` does not specify `var_list`.

That is, `Saver` will save all global variables and saveable variables by default.

```
def _all_saveable_objects():
  """Returns all variables and `SaveableObject`s that must be checkpointed.

  Returns:
    A list of `Variable` and `SaveableObject` to be checkpointed
  """
  # TODO(andreasst): make this function public once things are settled.
  return (ops.get_collection(ops.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) +
          ops.get_collection(ops.GraphKeys.SAVEABLE_OBJECTS))
```