# How to load batches of CSV files using tf.data and map

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been searching for an answer as to how I should go about this for quite some time and can't seem to find anything that works.

I am following a tutorial on using the tf.data API found [here](https://kratzert.github.io/2017/06/15/example-of-tensorflows-new-input-pipeline.html). My scenario is very similar to the one in this tutorial (i.e. I have 3 directories containing all the training/validation/test files), however, they are not images, they're spectrograms saved as CSVs.

I have found a couple solutions for reading lines of a CSV where each line is a training instance (e.g., [How to *actually* read CSV data in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091899/how-to-actually-read-csv-data-in-tensorflow)). But my issue with this implementation is the required `record_defaults` parameter as the CSVs are 500x200.

Here is what I was thinking:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

def load_data(path, label):
   # This obviously doesn't work because path and label
   # are Tensors, but this is what I had in mind...
   data = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=0).values()
   return data, label

X_train = tf.constant(training_files)  # training_files is a list of the file names
Y_train = tf.constant(training_labels  # training_labels is a list of labels for each file

train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, Y_train))

# Here is where I thought I would do the mapping of 'load_data' over each batch
train_data = train_data.batch(64).map(load_data)

iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_data.output_types, \
                                           train_data.output_shapes)
next_batch = iterator.get_next()
train_op = iterator.make_initializer(train_data)
```

I have only used Tensorflows `feed_dict` in the past, but I need a different approach now that my data has gotten to the size that it can no longer fit in memory.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you describe with `record_defaults`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @mikkola sure. As far as I can tell, reading the CSV line by line would require that I create a list of length 200 every time I wanted to read a file  (```record_defaults = [[0],[0],...,[0]]```) and then do something like ```cols = tf.decode_csv(csv_row, record_defaults=record_defaults)``` and ```data = tf.stack(cols)```. Which seemed like a lot of overhead for every file.

Comment: Ah, I see. Could still be worth a try? You only need to create one constant tensor to do that, and it can be shared between calls, right? Another option I have had success with was to read the whole file contents using [`tf.read_file`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/read_file), then split it appropriately (see `tf.string_split`) or directly interpret as CSV using [`tf.decode_csv`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/decode_csv).

Comment: I list of 200 tensors does not sound bad at all and you can reuse the same `tf.constant(0)` tensor. I would definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

I use Tensorflow (2.0) tf.data to read my csv dataset. I have several folders for each class. Each folder contains thousands of csv files of data points. Below is the code I use for the data input pipeline. Hope this helps.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def tf_parse_filename(filename):

    def parse_filename(filename_batch):
        data = []
        labels = []
        for filename in filename_batch:
            # Read data
            filename_str = filename.numpy().decode()
            # Read .csv file 
            data_point= np.loadtxt(filename_str, delimiter=',')

            # Create label
            current_label = get_label(filename)
            label = np.zeros(n_classes, dtype=np.float32)
            label[current_label] = 1.0

            data.append(data_point)
            labels.append(label)

        return np.stack(data), np.stack(labels)


    x, y = tf.py_function(parse_filename, [filename], [tf.float32, tf.float32])
    return x, y

train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(TRAIN_FILES)
train_ds = train_ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
train_ds = train_ds.map(tf_parse_filename, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

#Train on epochs
for i in range(num_epochs):
    # Train on batches
    for x_train, y_train in train_ds:
        train_step(x_train, y_train)

print('Training done!')
```

"TRAIN_FILES" is a matrix  (e.g. pandas dataframe) where the first column is the label of a data point and the second column is the path to the csv file containing the data point.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest looking at this thread. It provides a complete example for how to use dataset API to read data from multiple csv files.

[Tensorflow Python reading 2 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525056/tensorflow-python-reading-2-files/49548224#49548224)

Addendum:

Not sure how relevant the problem is as of today.. After seeing the comment that
@markdjthomas mentions that the problem is slightly different here and he needs to read several rows instead of one at a time. The following example can come handy as well. Sharing here, just in case anyone else needs it too...

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops import sliding

sequence = np.array([ [[1]], [[2]], [[3]], [[4]], [[5]], [[6]], [[7]], [[8]], [[9]] ])
labels = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]

# create TensorFlow Dataset object
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((sequence, labels))

# sliding window batch
window_size = 3
window_shift = 1
data = data.apply(sliding.sliding_window_batch(window_size=window_size, window_shift=window_shift))
data = data.shuffle(1000, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
data = data.batch(3)
#iter = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
iter = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(data.output_types, data.output_shapes)
el = iter.get_next()
# create initialization ops 
init_op = iter.make_initializer(data)

NR_EPOCHS = 3
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for e in range (NR_EPOCHS):
      print("\nepoch: ", e, "\n")
      sess.run(init_op)
      print("1  ", sess.run(el))
      print("2  ", sess.run(el))
      print("3  ", sess.run(el))
```

And the output...

```
epoch:  0 

1   (array([[[[5]],

        [[6]],

        [[7]]],


       [[[4]],

        [[5]],

        [[6]]],


       [[[1]],

        [[2]],

        [[3]]]]), array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]], dtype=int32))
2   (array([[[[3]],

        [[4]],

        [[5]]],


       [[[2]],

        [[3]],

        [[4]]],


       [[[7]],

        [[8]],

        [[9]]]]), array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]], dtype=int32))
3   (array([[[[6]],

        [[7]],

        [[8]]]]), array([[0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32))

epoch:  1 

1   (array([[[[1]],

        [[2]],

        [[3]]],


       [[[6]],

        [[7]],

        [[8]]],


       [[[2]],

        [[3]],

        [[4]]]]), array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32))
2   (array([[[[5]],

        [[6]],

        [[7]]],


       [[[3]],

        [[4]],

        [[5]]],


       [[[7]],

        [[8]],

        [[9]]]]), array([[1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]], dtype=int32))
3   (array([[[[4]],

        [[5]],

        [[6]]]]), array([[0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32))

epoch:  2 

1   (array([[[[1]],

        [[2]],

        [[3]]],


       [[[5]],

        [[6]],

        [[7]]],


       [[[2]],

        [[3]],

        [[4]]]]), array([[1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32))
2   (array([[[[4]],

        [[5]],

        [[6]]],


       [[[3]],

        [[4]],

        [[5]]],


       [[[7]],

        [[8]],

        [[9]]]]), array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]], dtype=int32))
3   (array([[[[6]],

        [[7]],

        [[8]]]]), array([[0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but this isn't really what I am looking for as each line is not a unique training example. The entire file is a single training example (ie: a 2d array).